# Call a function if a cell value is changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

A function called newsale() works perfectly for me. Code of the function is

```js
var SpreadsheetID = "1gZVKLqfk0SEKBEhuzgGKL7QqIEXLjgfV-8n-1tKDrho";
var SheetName = "Sale";

function newsale() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SpreadsheetID)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SheetName);
  var columnToCheck = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var lastRow = getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck);
  var lastRow1 = lastRow + 1;
  //Logger.log(lastRow);
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow, 6).getValue();
  //Logger.log(value);
  var cellno = "F" + lastRow1;
  //Logger.log(cellno);
  var value1 = value + 1;
  sheet.getRange(cellno).setValue(value1);

};

function getLastRowSpecial(range) {
  var rowNum = 0;
  var blank = false;
  for (var row = 0; row < range.length; row++) {

    if (range[row][0] === "" && !blank) {
      rowNum = row;
      blank = true;
    } else if (range[row][0] !== "") {
      blank = false;
    };
  };
  return rowNum;
};
```

I need to call this function if the value of 'Sale'!F4 is changed. How can I do that?

Comment: If the change is due to a user edit() you can use onEdit() trigger. If it's not the direct result of a user action then there is no such trigger. Then your only alternative is to use a time based trigger to poll the condition of that cell at regular time intervals. If you have a webapp that you can allow to run continuously you can poll it from the client with setInterval() or setTimeout() or you can use the server based timeBased Triggers.

Comment: Thanks. The user will change the value from a dropdown at F4. Then the function newsale() should run ...

Comment: Have you created and installable onEdit() trigger that points to newsale()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onEdit()` function, which is a  simple trigger in Apps Script. It will trigger every time a cell is edited by you and you can set a condition to check if it was the cell you wanted and then do something there.

Here is a little example that you can use to integrate it to your function (your function newSale now must be called onEdit()):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get row and column from the edit's cell
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var column = e.range.getColumn();

  // Check if it is the cell you want 
  if(row === 4 && column === 6){
    // Do something with the value when that cell value is edited 
    var myVal = e.range.getValues();
    Logger.log(myVal);
  }

}
```

### Edit

You have to call your function `newSale` now as `onEdit`, if you still want to use the name `newSale`, In your Apps Script project, do this:

1) Go Edit->Current project's triggers

2) Click Add Trigger

3) In "Choose which function to run" choose `newSale`

4) In "Select event source" choose *From spreadsheet*

5) In "Select event type" choose *On edit*

### Docs

In these docs, you can learn more about it and the trigger restrictions:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Event Obect Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: It gives an error msg : TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code") :(

Comment: It gives you that error because the ```e``` object is empty. I edited my answer to help you understand better how to set the event trigger

Comment: I'm really sorry for the delayed response. Thanks a lot for your time dude.